# How to fix Null Pointer Exception in Junit test?

Tags: spring, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception as shown in the code when I run the following Junit test. Can someone please help me fix it?

```
import com.apexsct.pouservice.amq.inboxlistener.GetUpdateAvailablePositionInfo;
import com.apexsct.servcomm.amq.pouservice.dto.DeliveryPositionData;

public class GetUpdateAvailablePositionInfoActionTest {
    @Mock
    protected PositionRepository positionRepo;

    @Mock
    protected UserInterfaceGroupRepository uiGroupRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private GetUpdateAvailablePositionInfo service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyRequest() {
        DeliveryPositionData response = (DeliveryPositionData) service.perform(); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
        assertEquals(ErrorMessageConstant.INVALID_REQUEST, response.getErrMsg());
    }

}
```

Comment: `service` is `null`.

Comment: I comes down to the question where is `request` coming from? If you do not inject it via (@Mock) you need to provide it in another way to your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your test name you want to test a case where the request is empty.
However you still need to supply an actual object, as your code does not
handle the case where `request` is null.

You could adjust the test to look like this:

```
public class GetUpdateAvailablePositionInfoActionTest {

    @Mock
    protected PositionRepository positionRepo;

    @Mock
    protected UserInterfaceGroupRepository uiGroupRepo;

    @Mock // creates and injects a mock for the request
    UpdAvlbPosRequest request;

    @InjectMocks
    private GetUpdateAvailablePositionInfo service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyRequest() {

        // defines that the sn of the request is an empty string
        // (Depending on what StringUtils class you use, it might also handle null correctly. 
        //  In this case this line can be removed)
        Mockito.when(request.getSn()).thenReturn("");

        DeliveryPositionData response = (DeliveryPositionData) service.perform();
        assertEquals(ErrorMessageConstant.INVALID_REQUEST, response.getErrMsg());
    }
}
```